# Git push again the same commit to remote

Tags: git, gitlab, push, commit, remote-branch

My project has a remote and local synchronized repository.

1. I did locally new branch -> than committed and pushed to the remote.
2. Next, I have unaware deleted remote branch - operation is impossible to undo(in Gitlab).

So, locally I have everything OK only my remote repository need to be updated.

How to push again the same commit to remote?

(I do everything in Intellij and one time pushed commit is no more visible there and of course not possible to push again)

Thanks for any help.

Comment: There should be a way to update local repository with remote updates. Usually you do that using `git fetch`. Once you do that you should be able to push again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the remote branch is completely deleted, You can directly push your local branch to remote

`git push origin <local-branch-name>`

or in Intellij while on your branch press `Ctrl+Shift+k` and push

Every commit in your local branch should appear in remote

Comment: Thanks a lot! Push again whole branch in terminal solved my problem. In Intellij Ctrl+Shift+k opens 'push' window and there is no commit to push again, because it was pushed previously.

Comment: I am glad it worked out. In Intellij the reason there is no commit because there is no remote branch, so Intellij trying to show the whole new branch. If you press the push button it will work as same as terminal.